# Patent Drafting Software

Tags: drafting

Does anyone know of any good patent drafting software? The software I am thinking of will automate some of the aspects of patent drafting and may reduce careless errors.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not confident this is necessarily on topic, since there's not really any specific answer: it's more canvassing for thoughts. Which is a shame, because it's something I'm rather interested in. I wonder if you might think of a way to make it more concretely answerable, rather than asking for opinions?

Answer (score 1):

I am an inventor and have worked with quite a few patent attorneys both inside and outside my company. In every case, the patents were written using Microsoft Word. It is important to understand that the drafting of an application is an iterative process where the attorney/agent creates a draft and the inventor(s) review and comment. This pretty much limits you to commonly available word processing software since the inventors are unlikely to have specialized legal software.

I can imagine that there would be a need for broader patent management activities such as organizing prior art results and citations, managing communications with patent offices and tracking deadlines and required payments. If you could describe those needs specifically, I would recommend you post a question on the [Software Recommendation SE site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).